# Why Does clearInterval only works the first time?

Tags: javascript

This is my code below:

```
function triggerTimer() {
    var myInt = window.setInterval(timerStart, 1000);
    setTimeout(removeInt, 4000);
}
function timerStart() {
    var timerValue = parseInt(document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML);
    if (timerValue > 0) {
        timerValue -= 1;
        document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML = '0' +timerValue.toString();
        console.log(timerValue);

    }
    else {
        var correct = document.getElementById(`c${row}`).innerHTML;
        multiplechoice.innerHTML = '<p>The correct answer is <span style="color: white;" id=`c${row}`>'+correct+'</span><br><button onclick="submitEntry();">Next Question</button></p>';
    }
}
function removeInt() {
    if(clearInterval(myInt)) {console.log('success')} else {console.log('fail')}
}
```

Above this code is a timer that decreases every time timerStart function is called. The problem is that the timer stops the first time removeInt function is triggered, even though it logs 'fail'.

But the second time timerStart is triggered, the time still decreases, but when removeInt is called, the interval isn't cleared.

Comment: Read the [documentation](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/clearInterval#return_value). The return value of `clearInterval` is `undefined`. Where did you get the idea to put a `clearInterval` call into an `if` condition?

Comment: Have you fixed the error reported on the console that `myInt` is not defined in `removeInt`? (Because `myInt` is defined in `triggerTime` and only has function scope.)

Comment: @traktor There won't be any error because of javascript hoisting. `myInt` is a var so it will be moved and defined at top before the code execution.

Comment: @UtkarshDixit No, traktor is right, `myInt` is out of scope. Hoisting doesn’t cross function boundaries.

Comment: @SebastianSimon My bad, I was under the impression that javascript hoisting moves the declaration to the starting of code execution (instead of moving to the top of their scopes). Thanks for correcting me

Comment: I found a solution and that is by putting the function removeInt within triggerTimer. I replaced the removeInt in setTimeout with the commands on removeInt function, and then removed the removeInt function itself.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting `failed` logged because clearInterval returns undefined even when it is successful.

So your `removeInt` function,

```
if(clearInterval(myInt)) {console.log('success')} else {console.log('fail')}
```

is getting evaluated like this,

```
if(undefined) {console.log('success')} else {console.log('fail')}
```

Here's a doc about `clearInterval` for more info, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/clearInterval